# Is it possible to configure hibernate.ddl-auto separately for different entities / tables?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my Spring Boot project I am opening access to an external database, where some tables are already defined.

I want to add some new @Entity classes and auto-update schema.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
}
```

So I define a property for that in my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**But how can I prevent updating the schema, when I add a field to already existing @Entity class (e.g. accidentally), that maps "old" tables, which I must not change.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to configure schema generation behavior at entity level.

To have better control over database schema evolution, it is recommended to use flyway or liquibase instead of relying on hibernate schema generation.

Comment: Thanks. Reading about flyway, looks good